# Copy row from one table to another table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have problem with insert and delete row in MySQL command. I want to copy one row from `table1` to `table2`.

```
commandSQL.CommandText = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE simnum=@simnum AND msg=@msg;" +
                         "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE simnum= @simnum AND msg= @msg";
commandSQL.Prepare();
commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@simnum", argumentComport[2]);
commandSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", argumentComport[1]);

commandSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Anyone help me?

---

Command INSERT and DELETE is not execute.

---

yes I call `Open()`. Another SQL command is work. But this not.
`commandSQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text` - Its default setting

Comment: @duDE Based on the accepted answer, looks like this was nothing but a typo (table1 vs. table2 in the `DELETE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL looks a little strange:

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE simnum=@simnum AND msg=@msg;" +
"DELETE FROM table1 WHERE simnum= @simnum AND msg= @msg";
```

You are inserting into table1 and instantly deleting from table1 afterwards.

Could you also try adding `commandSQL.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` at the top.
Have you also called Open on your SqlConnection object?

Do you get an exceptions? Hope this helps.